# while loop mysql/PHP exceeds execution time

Tags: php, mysql, loops

This while loop causes a Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. 
The query IS working. I tested the query in phpmyadmin.

Nothing is inside the loop in order to test whether it's content caused the error.
It looks like the while loop is overloading. It seems that the script takes too long to load (thinking the query is too extended), not seeing any possibilities the loop to be infinite.

```
while($tags_db = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, 
"SELECT * 
FROM zk_terms 
WHERE parent_id = 1 AND parent_type = 'archive' AND taxonomy = 'tag'"))){

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the while loop?

Comment: It's not finite - each iteration you're performing a query and fetching the first row from it. If you didn't put everything into single line it would be obvious for you too.

Comment: I left nothing inside the while loop to check whether the content of the loop was causing the error. But still without any script inside, it's running into problems.

Comment: What you're saying @zerkms is that I have to create two lines? First line: `$tags_db = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM zk_terms WHERE parent_id = 1 AND parent_type = 'archive' AND taxonomy = 'tag'"))` Second line: `while($tags_db)`?

Comment: @TomGroot It doesn't matter how many lines you put the query string on... read your answers below.

Comment: @Mark: it **does** matter how many statements you have. It's impossible to do what OP is doing in a single statement

Comment: @zerkms Statements, yes, lines of SQL, no. I was referring to his edit where he split the SQL on to multiple lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're re-executing the query every iteration, and then `mysqli_fetch_array` is fetching only the first result each loop. You have to move `mysqli_query` outside the loop and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, 
"SELECT * 
FROM zk_terms 
WHERE parent_id = 1 AND parent_type = 'archive' AND taxonomy = 'tag'");

while($tags_db = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your mysqli_query command outside your while and catch the result in a variable. Then use the variable with mysqli_fetch_array in the while .

otherwise, everytime the while condition is examined, the query is run again